# Clipping pdf with itextsharp 5 results in a corrupt PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to read a PDF file using itextsharp 5, and create a new PDF file with the left half of each page of the original PDF, discarding the right half. I wrote the following code, but the result is corrupt and cannot be opened with Acrobat Reader (opening it with Chrome works though). How can I make a PDF that works with Acrobat Reader?

```
private byte[] ObtenerMitadPdf(byte[] Contenido)
    {
        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(Contenido))
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var documento = new Document())
                using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documento, memoryStream))
                {
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                    documento.Open();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        var pagina = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
                        var tamañoPagina = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                        var nuevoTamaño = new Rectangle(tamañoPagina.Left, tamañoPagina.Bottom,
                            tamañoPagina.Left + (tamañoPagina.Width / 2), tamañoPagina.Top, tamañoPagina.Rotation);
                        if (tamañoPagina.Rotation == 90)
                        {
                            pdfWriter.DirectContent.AddTemplate(pagina, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, tamañoPagina.Height);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pdfWriter.DirectContent.AddTemplate(pagina, 0, 0);
                        }
                        documento.SetPageSize(nuevoTamaño);
                        documento.NewPage();
                    }
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't put `var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documento, memoryStream)` into a `using` block. Closing the `Document` will implicitly close the `PdfWriter`. Other than that your approach is unnecessarily complicated, you can simply change the crop boxes of the `PdfReader` and write that version using a ` PdfStamper`.

Comment: How do I set the crop box with PdfReader? Does it take rotation into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working!

```
private byte[] ObtenerMitadPdf(byte[] Contenido)
    {
        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(Contenido))
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream))
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        var pagina = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
                        var tamañoPagina = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                        var mediaBox = new PdfRectangle(tamañoPagina.Left, tamañoPagina.Bottom,
                            tamañoPagina.Left + (tamañoPagina.Width / 2), tamañoPagina.Top, tamañoPagina.Rotation);
                        pagina.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, mediaBox);
                        stamper.MarkUsed(pagina);
                    }
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();                   
            }
        }
    }
```